# Python Requests untrusted certificate

Tags: python, ssl

I am using python 2.7 `requests module` to make a web crawler. But I am having trouble while making requests to a site that requires certificate. When I made `requests.get(url)`, it throws `sslError, certificate verify failed, ok.`

So, I tried `requests.get(url, verify=False)`, it works but it returns meta `http-equiv="refresh" url='...'`, and the url is not the one I made the request. Is there a way to solve this problem or a need to send the certificate?

I saw in requests doc that I can send the certificate and the key. I have the `certificate.crt`, but I don't have the key, is there a way to get the key?
The certificate is AC certisign multipla G5 and uses TLS 1.2

Comment: Sounds like the page does a redirect/forward by using a page refresh, rather than a server-side redirect, so I'm not seeing any problems yet. As for the certificate - are you the one in charge of the webpage and the SSL certificate it uses? Sounds like it's a self-signed cert on the host's end, and `requests` doesn't like those without the `verify=False` parameter you pass.

Comment: Seems more like their site doesn't allow direct access to that URL and so it will redirect you to the portal. You might have to find a different way to access it, or it may require authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of trying to solve this issue, I figured it out. The problem was not with the `SSL` certificate.

I was making a request to a web page that needs a session; The url that I was using is redirected from another page. To access it correctly, I had to send a request to that page and get the last redirected page.

So, what I did was using Requests' `Session` method:

```
Session.get(url, verify=False)
```

where the `url` is the redirecting url.